# Parse.com code won't deploy: "Could not load triggers"

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

There is a good chance I did something wrong, but I tried to combine [the code at this page on GET requests](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#networking) [with code to send pushes through background jobs,](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending/JavaScript) to create code that can fetch [the price of a bitcoin](https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD/last), and send it as a push, if the grab is successful. Here is my code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);

Parse.Cloud.job("sendAlert", function(sendAlert, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD/last',
     success: function(httpResponse) {
       console.log(httpResponse.text);
       Parse.Push.send({
         where: query, // Set our Installation query
    data: {
        alert: (httpResponse.text)
    }
}, {
success: function() {
    status.success("Push Worked!!!");
 },
error: function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.")
 }
});
},
    error: function(httpResponse) {
console.error('Request failed with response code ' +     httpResponse.status);
  }
});
```

Note: I can't seem to figure out how to get the formatting right in the above block - here is a photo of it as it is in my editor. [image]

The code has the intended function of pulling the price of 1 BTC in USD from [this site](https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/global/USD/last), and sending it as a push notification.

I am sure I have terribly butchered something, but my code won't deploy, with the error

```
Update failed with Could not load triggers.  The error was Uncaught You must specify a key using Parse.initialize.
```

. So, what can I fix to get the data from the plaintext API, and send it as a push? Or is there a better way to do that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a key at the very beginning:

```
Parse.initialize("APPLICATION ID", "JAVASCRIPT KEY");
```